# I have dual non-EU passports - can I back-to-back two 90-day EU stays using the two passports?

Tags: dual-nationality, eu, 90-180-visa-rules

I am a citizen of two non-EU countries, both of which are allowed 90-day visa-free stays in the EU. Can I stay in the EU 90 days on one passport, leave the EU for one day then re-enter the EU on the other passport for a further 90 days? Looking to spend (up to) 6 months straight in the EU without breaking visa rules. Which comes first - the passport or the individual I guess?

Comment: We had this question before. I will look for that question. But the answer is that it is 90 days in 180 days for the person. So no new period with the other passport.

Comment: The two passports don’t change anything to the 90/180 rule which applies to the person. However there are some combinations of nationalities and countries you may wish to stay in which have different rules (US citizens in Poland for instance).

Comment: @Willeke The other question is about the possibility of doing so in any country. This is appears about the legality specific to the EU.